# jQuery Mobile + Flexslider2

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, flexslider

I'm having huge troubles getting jQuery Mobile to work with other Javascript libraries - in my case Flexslider 2 (http://flex.madebymufffin.com/examples/basic.html).

I have a couple of pages where I want to use the flexslider in addition to jQM. Unfortunately, the slider doesn't work / isn't loaded when I click on links on my site.

I know this is because of the way jQM loads pages - by loading them with AJAX and adding them do the DOM.

I've been looking around for hours now to find out how to use events like "pageshow" and "mobileinit" etc but I just can't get it to work, so any help is really appreciated.

Heres what I'm doing now:

In each < head > part of my pages:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#flexslider').bind('pageshow', function(){
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
        });
    });
</script>
```

This works when I reload the page manually, however it doesn't work when I visit the page through a link on my site.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `rel="external"` or `data-ajax="false"` to the link of FlexSlider page, which can disable the Ajax loading of page. You can refer to the document [here](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try putting it inside a callback of pageinit. Like so...

```
$(document).bind('pageinit', function(){ $('.flexslider').flexslider({ animation: 'slide' ); });
```

I'm sure someone more knowledgable can chime in as to why this is necessary, but I'm 99% sure it's the way to go.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Flexslider on the index page of a Jquery Mobile site would work when first navigated to, but not if returned to through the menu or back button.

I used the 'pageshow' event rather than the ''pageinit' event and it worked perfectly:

$(document).bind('pageshow', function() {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide", 
  });
});